# Different ways to configure secure connection

Tags: java, spring, struts, web.xml

I used to configure secure connections within web.xml (security-constraint)

Recently I figured out that

- spring (FilterChainProxy)
- struts

are offering also secure connection within their configuration files.

What are the pro and cons to use these files instead of web.xml?

Comment: What do you mean by "secure connection"? Do you mean for authentication and general security or for requiring TLS/HTTPS transfer?

Comment: "secure(d) connection" is a standard term in JEE/Web technology. SSL/TLS/Https is just one way to implement it, even when it is commonly used. In none of the three mentioned configurations you are required to talk about TLS/SSL/https. This may be done in tomcat's server.xml for example.